# Is it upgrade safe to add custom address attributes

Tags: magento

currently i am developing a Magento extension, that needs to add several custom attributes to customer address.
I've found several tutorials on the topic that describe precisely what i need to build
http://www.unexpectedit.com/magento/add-new-customer-attribute-onepage-magento-checkout
http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address

They all use ALTER TABLE to add columns to several db tables.My question is :

Is it upgrade safe to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using the magento framework method addAttribute() not pure SQL queries. They're using it in an upgrade script and it's its purpose : to upgrade safely a database..

Note that the EAV mechanims of the customer entity is built in order to not alter the table definition but add data in it. So in the background customer::addAttribute doesn't do a single ALTER TABLE. On the contrary, the now flated-tables sales_flat_order/quote addAttribute method does alter the tables cause it's no more an EAV entity.

They're doing it right.

I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Hi, Bixi my question was about the two ALTER TABLE statements described at the very end of this article :http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address.Anyway i found an answer here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/is-it-upgrade-safe-to-add-custom-address-attributes.Thank you, anyway!

Comment: Ha ok I didn't read that part. As I told you, alter tables for sales_flat tables are the only way to add data as it's not an EAV entity. Though, instead of making direct ALTER TABLE query, I would use the framework : 
`$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote'), 'govt_id', array('TYPE' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 'LENGTH' => '255', 'NULLABLE' => false));`

Comment: But is this safe in terms of upgrade?